# Remove python dict item from nested json file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that I fetch from an API that returns KeyError:0 while I attempt to remove items in a python dict. I assume its a combination of my lack of skill and format of the json.

My goal is to remove all instances of `192.168.1.1` from `ip_address_1`

My Code:

```
from api import Request
import requests, json, ordereddict

# prepare request
request = Request().service('').where({"query":"192.168.1.0"}).withType("json")

# call request
response = request.execute()

# parse response into python object
obj = json.loads(response)

# remove items
for i in xrange(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]["ip_address_1"] == "192.168.1.1":
        obj.pop(i)

# display
print json.dumps(obj,indent=1)
```

Example JSON:

```
{
 "response": {
  "alerts": [
   {
    "action": "New",
    "ip_address_1": "192.168.1.1",
    "domain": "example.com",
    "ip_address_2": "192.68.1.2"
   },
   {
    "action": "New",
    "ip_address_1": "192.168.1.3",
    "domain": "example2.com",
    "ip_address_2": "192.168.1.1"
   }
  ],
  "total": "2",
  "query": "192.168.1.0",
 }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want `[alert['ip_address_1'] for alert in obj['response']['alerts'] if alert['ip_address_1'] != '192.168.1.1']`. Is that a correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: That was the original logic, however I would like to break it up into two parts, reducing the data set and then printing a section. I'll give the second part another try and post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

This is incorrect:

```
# remove items
for i in xrange(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]["ip_address_1"] == "192.168.1.1":
        obj.pop(i)
```

You are iterating over an object as if it were a list.

What you want to do:

```
for sub_obj in obj["response"]["alerts"]:
    if sub_obj["ip_address_1"] == "192.168.1.1":
        sub_obj.pop("ip_address_1")
```

Comment: I receive the following error. Do I need to do something with response before alerts?

for sub_obj in obj["alerts"]:
KeyError: 'alerts'

Comment: What does `obj` look like? Can you print that out?

Comment: {u'response': {u'alerts': [{u'action': u'New', u'ip_address_1': u'192.168.1.1', u'domain': u'example.com', u'ip_address_2': u'192.168.1.2'}, {u'action': u'New'

Answer (score 1):

I've interpreted your requirements to be:

1. Remove from the "alerts" list any dictionary with `ip_address_1` set
   to `192.168.1.1`.
2. Create a list of all other `ip_address_1` values.

`json.loads(response)` produces this dictionary:

```
{u'response': {u'alerts': [{u'action': u'New',
                            u'domain': u'example.com',
                            u'ip_address_1': u'192.168.1.1',
                            u'ip_address_2': u'192.68.1.2'},
                           {u'action': u'New',
                            u'domain': u'example2.com',
                            u'ip_address_1': u'192.168.1.3',
                            u'ip_address_2': u'192.168.1.1'}],
               u'query': u'192.168.1.0',
               u'total': u'2'}}
```

The "alerts" list is accessed by (assuming the dict is bound to `obj`):

```
>>> obj['response']['alerts']
[{u'action': u'New',
  u'domain': u'example.com',
  u'ip_address_1': u'192.168.1.1',
  u'ip_address_2': u'192.68.1.2'},
 {u'action': u'New',
  u'domain': u'example2.com',
  u'ip_address_1': u'192.168.1.3',
  u'ip_address_2': u'192.168.1.1'}]
```

The first part can be done like this:

```
alerts = obj['response']['alerts']
obj['response']['alerts'] = [d for d in alerts if d.get('ip_address_1') != '192.168.1.1']
```

Here a list comprehension is used to filter out those dictionaries with `ip_address_1` 192.168.1.1 and the resulting list is then rebound the the `obj` dictionary. After this `obj` is:

```
>>> pprint(obj)
{u'response': {u'alerts': [{u'action': u'New',
                            u'domain': u'example2.com',
                            u'ip_address_1': u'192.168.1.3',
                            u'ip_address_2': u'192.168.1.1'}],
               u'query': u'192.168.1.0',
               u'total': u'2'}}
```

Next, creating a list of the other ip addresses is easy with another list comprehension run on the alerts list ***after*** removing the undesired dicts as shown above:

```
ip_addresses = [d['ip_address_1'] for d in obj['response']['alerts'] if d.get('ip_address_1') is not None]
```

Notice that we use `get()` to handle the possibility that some dictionaries might not have a `ip_address_1` key.

```
>>> ip_addresses
[u'192.168.1.3']
```