# Remove Python dict from JSON file response

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've looked over a few resources such as the following: [Remove python dict item from nested json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706841/remove-python-dict-item-from-nested-json-file#) but cannot seem to get my code to work. From what I understand of my JSON below (which is a variable placeholder for a WAY longer dump), it's a dict with a dict inside of it with a dict inside of that with....lists randomly inside of it. What I ultimately want to see is the following printout to my Terminal:

```
Message: [Client ID] 
Link: "http://linkgoeshere.com"
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
ThreeLine= {u'hits': {u'hits': [{u'_id': u'THIS IS THE FIRST ONE',
                  u'_index': u'foo',
                  u'_score': None,
                  u'_source': {u'@timestamp': u'2015-12-21T16:59:40.000-05:00',
                               u'message': u'Application.INFO: [Client ID ] Information Link: http://google.com {"check1":121212} {"tags":{"sent":"15","HTML":"5661"},"person":"15651"}',
                               u'system': u'user-info'}},
                {u'_id': u'THIS IS THE SECOND ONE',
                  u'_index': u'two',
                  u'_score': None,
                  u'_source': {u'@timestamp': u'2015-12-12 T16:59:40.000-05:00',
                               u'message': u'Application.INFO: [Client ID ] Information Link: http://google.com {"check1":565656} {"tags":{"sent":"21","HTML":"4512"},"person":"15651"}',
                               u'system': u'user-info'}},
]}}

unpacking= ThreeLine['hits']['hits'] #we only want to talk to the sort dictionary. 


for d in unpacking:
    newinfo= []
    narrow=[d["_source"] for d in unpacking if "_source" in d] 
    narrower=[d["message"] for d in narrow if "message" in d]
    newinfo.append(narrower)
print newinfo
```

Right now, with the code as it is, it'll print both entries, but it has a lot of random junk I don't care about, like all of the tags:

```
{"tags":{"sent":"21","HTML":"4512"},"person":"15651"}',
```

So, how do I further strip out those entries so I just wind up with the two lines I ultimately want out of this insanely nested mess? If anyone has ideas for how I can clean up the current code, I'm all ears and ready to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'tags' dictionary is not a dictionary. It is *text* embedded in the message string:

```
>>> ThreeLine['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['message']
u'Application.INFO: [Client ID ] Information Link: http://google.com {"check1":121212} {"tags":{"sent":"15","HTML":"5661"},"person":"15651"}'
```

You'll have to do some string parsing to remove that. You could use a regular expression:

```
import re
id_and_link = re.compile(r'(\[[^]]+\]) Information Link: (https?://[\w\d/.]+)')

messages = (entry['_source']['message'] for entry in ThreeLine['hits']['hits'] if '_source' in entry and 'message' in entry['_source'])
for message in messages:
    match = id_and_link.search(message)
    if not match:
        continue
    id_, link = match.groups()
    print 'Message:', id_
    print 'Link:', link
    print
```

Comment: Hm, this doesn't give me anything. Any ideas why?

Comment: @SamW: probably because your *real* data is subtly different and thus the regular expression doesn't match. Give us some `message` values that are real, rather than made up for the question.

Comment: I got it figured out, Monday brain. :) Thank you so much!